# Calculating collectionView cell height dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im currently attempting to calculate the height of a `UICollectionViewCell` dynamically but using a `UILabel` (the dynamic property) and the current height of the cell. The height is calculated by getting height for `sizeThatFits` of the label within the cell and adding that value to the original height of the cell. For some reason this always returns 0 in `sizeForItemAt`. I'm pretty sure the problem is the size is being calculated before the cell is created thus will always return 0. Is there anyway around this?  (The UI for the cell is created within the class itself, not at celllForItemAt could that also be a problem?)

```
  var descHeight: CGFloat = 0

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "desc", for: indexPath) as! ImageDescCell
       descHeight = cell.descriptionLbl.sizeThatFits(cell.frame.size).height + cell.bounds.height
      return cell
    }
  }
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let w = collectionView.bounds.width
      return CGSize(width: w, height: descHeight)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSAttributedString can tell you how big an instance is, given a bound.  So assuming you know how wide the label is and you know what the text is and what its attributes are you can get the size without ever creating a label:

```
let width = CGFloat(200)
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Test", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)!])
let boundingRect = attributedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly, there's a bit of guess work on the width but I will refine that

Answer (score -1):

### swift-3.0

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
   let width = self.collectionView.frame.size.width
   let Height = self.view.frame.size.height - 64 // 64 is a navigation bar height minus.
   let cellSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: width, height: Height )
   return cellSize
}
```

Comment: Please give a brief description about what your code (given as answer) really does and how it will help in addressing the issue specified in the question.